# setOnclilcklistener for images of footer

Tags: android-widget

i am adding a footer having 2 imageviews to my app using include tag.
I am able to view the footer and access the image view ids in source code but am not able to setOnclicklistener to these imageviews.

**In main.xml i have**

include layout="@layout/common_footer"

**In common_footer.xml**

?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?
LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
android:background="#228b22"

ImageView android:id="@+id/image1" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:src="@drawable/icon" 
android:paddingRight="20px" 
android:clickable="false"

ImageView android:id="@+id/image2" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:src="@drawable/sample_0" 
android:clickable="false"

LinearLayout

**In source code**

View inflatedView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.common_footer, null);
        ImageView b = (ImageView)inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.image1);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT 
                ,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
        b.setLayoutParams(lp);
        b.setClickable(false);
        b.setSelected(false);
        b.setOnClickListener(mClickListener); 
    }

```
private OnClickListener mClickListener = new OnClickListener() 
{ 
        public void onClick(View v) 
        { 
            Intent i = new Intent(TableImageLayout.this, TableImageLayout2.class);
            startActivity(i);   
        } 
};
```

But my Onclicklistener is not working.

Please forward your valuable suggestions

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0):

Hello i have solved the issue 
Earlier i was using viewgroup as null.
View inflatedView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.common_footer, null);

the problem will be solved if we provide the view group as the parent layout.
As my layout is table layout tb.
View inflatedView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.common_footer, tb); works fine.